# Compile Java API package source code in Android API Level 22 Lollipop into class byte code files?

Tags: android

How do I compile Java API packages (e.g. Java.lang) source code in Android API Level 22 (Lollipop) into class byte code? Thank you!

UPDATE: Adding more info. Sorry the question was poorly formatted earlier. I am working on a hardware platform for IoT and need the Java packages into a different platform and need class files in the process.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? If you need a .jar output, you can compile the project as an Android library for example.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to compile the "luni" folder in the Android src. You can run javac with the proper classpath against all the java files in that folder. That should work.